# Moving mid-year to a no-state-income-tax state (Indiana to Washington)

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, washington, indiana

It is my understanding that if you move from one state to another mid-year, then, depending on the states and the details of the move, in each state, you are generally either taxed only on the exact income earned from the state you were a resident of for the period of the residency, or, alternatively (depending on the state) on the proportion of the total federal income as it relates to the income earned within the state.

What if one moves from Indiana to Washington within a single tax year?  Will the income from Washington be subject to Indiana's state income tax?

What if the income in Washington is disproportionally larger (by several orders of magnitude in absolute terms, and by 2×–3× on per annum basis) than that in Indiana?

Comment: JoeTaxpayer♦, Why is there a dispute about the content of this post?

Comment: I do not know about Indiana, but Vermont and NY have the equivalent of a standard deduction and income that is not taxable in the state lowers how much of the deduction can be taken. (Roughly) With orders of magnitude difference you may find that your Indiana taxes are higher even if they don't tax your Washington income.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Can you explain your last sentence. You seem to be saying if they tax their Washington income, and with all else being equal, they could pay less in taxes. I don't understand how taxing a larger portion of your income could ever mean paying less in taxes, if the only difference is the amount of income.

Comment: @Tyler. Sorry, was unclear. Higher than if you had no Washington state income. Say one making only $A only in VT has to pay $B. Making $A in VT and X times $A in WA may result in VT taxes, (well) above $B, even though they are not "taxing" any of the WA income. Ditto NY.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I'm not sure that's how it works. If you are paying more in taxes in VT because of the income you earned while living in WA, than they are "taxing" your WA income. If you are only paying taxes on what you made in VT, than it wouldn't matter what you made in WA, since your tax liability would only be the income you made while living in VT. I don't live in either state, so I'm not familiar with how they decide whether to tax all your income or just income earned while living in the state, but the only way you pay more is by having a larger income.

Comment: @Tyler the income that they tax you on is still the same, it's just that the bracket is different.  The expected rationale is that you shouldn't be able to skirt paying the fair share if you simply move between the neighbouring states.  Of course, in reality, what happens is that you get a real job in CA, after being a grad student in VA, and you end up with having to puff up the extra tax and penalties to VA all of a sudden, because your modest VA income is now taxed at the top bracket.

Comment: @cnst I'm still not following this logic. My understanding of progressive tax was that you pay the amount of each lower bracket, and then the percentage of your income in the highest bracket you fall in to. If you aren't being taxed on income from another state, why would the higher bracket matter? For example, and I'm just going to use even numbers to keep the math simple, but let's say the tax brackets are 0-$10k => 10%, $10k - $20k => 15%, $20k - $40k => 20%, $40k + => 25%. You have an income of $35K in VT and an income of $40k in WA. VT is only taxing the income you made while living there

Comment: @cnst The standard deduction is $10k, so you are only paying taxes on the $25k of income left in VT, since they aren't taxing the WA income. Using the brackets above, my understanding is you would pay 10% on your first $10k(0-$10k), $1k, 15% on your second $10k($10k-$20k), $1.5k, and 20% on the last $5k($20k-$25k), $1k. Even though your combined income would have put you in the 25% bracket, you never actually pay 25% on any of the income. Federally, you would still pay taxes on the combined amount, actually putting you in a higher bracket.

Comment: @Tyler They all have different formulae that you'd effectively have to reverse-engineer to see what's going on, but it appears that some states effectively do it on a percentage basis — X% is your income from within the state compared to all income; Y would be your tax liability if all income was within the state; you'd then pay X% of Y to your former state.  This math would make perfect sense if you move from VA to NC between the similar full-time jobs, but it may also results in big underpaying penalties (to the former state) for graduating students etc.

Comment: @cnst I don't think it is that complicated. As far as determining how much of your income is taxable, you may need to reverse-engineer formulas, but for the purpose of our conversation, what matters is what your taxable income is. If your taxable income is only the income earned in VT, then it wouldn't matter if your income from WA would put you in a higher tax bracket. What you pay is as simple as percentages on each bracket of taxable income. [VT state tax](https://www.bankrate.com/finance/taxes/state-taxes-vermont.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Its pretty clear, [if you read the instructions (page 8)](https://forms.in.gov/Download.aspx?id=10881):

> Nonresidency and income taxable to Indiana A part-year resident owes
>   tax on taxable income received from all sources while being a resident
>   of Indiana. A part-year or full-year nonresident also owes tax on
>   income from Indiana sources as listed below while a legal resident of
>   another state. Indiana income includes income from the following
>   sources:
>
> 1. Winnings from Indiana riverboats and lotteries;
> 2. Labor or services performed in Indiana, including salaries, wages, commissions, tips etc.;
> 3. A farm, business, trade or profession doing business in Indiana;
> 4. Any personal property located in Indiana;
> 5. A partnership or an S corporation doing business in Indiana;
> 6. Stocks, bonds, notes, bank deposits, patents, copyrights, secret processes and formulas, goodwill, trademarks, trade brands,
>      franchises, and other property where earnings are a part of an Indiana
>      business;
> 7. Trusts and estates given to nonresident heirs; and
> 8. Pensions and most interest and dividends are taxed by your state of residence when you receive them.
>
> **Note:** If you were a full-year
>   nonresident and your only income from Indiana sources was from
>   pensions, interest and/or dividends (which were not a basic part of
>   the business in Indiana) and/or unemployment compensation, you are not
>   required to file an Indiana income tax return.

First you need to [check if you're a part-year resident or a full-year resident](http://www.in.gov/dor/4732.htm) (you may still be a full-year resident in Indiana even if you move away, on certain conditions).

If you're full year resident - Indiana taxes all income. If you're part year resident - you file form IT-40PNR, and follow [the instructions in the booklet](https://forms.in.gov/Download.aspx?id=10881).